# How to create a double from a coefficient and a power of 10 in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, double, scientific-notation

What is a good way to create a double from a coefficient and a power of 10? Or in other words, what is a good way to create a double from the significand and the exponent of a written scientific notation value at runtime?

Comment: What's wrong with `coefficient * pow( 10.0, exponent)`?

Comment: For power of _two_, you could use [std::ldexp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ldexp), but for power of 10 `std::pow` is all you've got.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "scientific notation value" - scientific notation is a textual representation of values.

Comment: Indeed. So unless this involves some string handling routines, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. I fixed the phrasing in the question.

Comment: `double d = 5.4313e6;`

Comment: I'm talking about during runtime. Sorry for being so vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about numerical quality, but the obvious way would be:

```
double make_double(double coefficient, int power)
{
  return coefficient * pow(10.0, power);
}
```

Comment: If you are worried about numerical quality, then to play safe you could write a string and pass it to `strtod`. The precision of the coefficient might still cause problems, but there's not a lot you can do about inaccuracies that are already there in your input.